# Show variable outside for loop shopify

Tags: loops, variables, shopify, liquid

I am trying to show the selected value in Shopify outside the for loop. 
How do I show the selected radio option in the label after "Color:"? I want to display it where it says "SHOW SELECTED OPTION".

Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
<label>Color: SHOW SELECTED OPTION</label>

<fieldset class="single-option-color-selector"
  id="ProductSelect-option-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
  {% assign option_index = forloop.index %}
  {% for value in option.values %}
    {% assign variant_label_state = true %}
    {% if product.options.size == 1 %}
      {% unless product.variants[forloop.index0].available  %}
        {% assign variant_label_state = false %}
      {% endunless %}
    {% endif %}
    <input type="radio"
      {% if option.selected_value == value %} checked="checked"{% endif %}
      value="{{ value | escape }}"
      data-index="option{{ option_index }}"
      name="color"
      class="single-option-selector__radio"
      id="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | escape }}">
    <label class="option-color-{{ value | escape }}" for="ProductSelect-option-{{ option.name | handleize }}-{{ value | escape }}" title="{{ value | escape }}">{{ value | escape }}</label>
  {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you shared, it looks like you can try this:

```
<label>Color: {{ option.selected_value }}</label>
```